# How to calculate between dates in a ListView in Android and show the result in a new field in the same row?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview

I am new at Android and also at StackOverflow as a registered user. I have been using this site a lot, but this is the first time that I need help and I could not find an answer.

I need to show in a ListView the diference in days between today and the date picked from a datepicker. I have the data in a SQLite data base. Where should I do the maths for this? In my CursorAdapter Class, or in the Cursor?

Because I need to change the color of the text if the expiration date for doing something is less than 2 days for instance. And that is why I need to do this on my listView to show the user which activities are close to be expired.

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Gretel

Comment: soooo, lets say today is 1/1/17. I choose 1/5/17. You want your list view to do what exactly? You need to look at GregorianCalendar for one...

Comment: Why not just calculate the date difference directly in your sql statement when you query your Sqlite DB?

Answer (score 0):

Let Sqlite do the math for you by calculating the date difference directly in the database query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT myNameCol as name, julianday('now') - julianday(myDateColumn) as dayDiff FROM MyTable;
```

The returned value for `dayDiff`is the difference in days from `now` and the value in the `myDateColumn` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I will try it and I will let you know how it was!